# Content Provider not working

Tags: android

I am using Xperia which runs on ICS. Here is an app that I wrote as a way to understand the working of Content Providers. The application runs fine on GingerBread emulator but does not shows a thing in my phone. Whats the prob which is causing app to behave like this ?
Here is code for android manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="legacy_systems.contentprovider"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="legacy_systems.contentprovider.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the code for layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android:lst"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:transcriptMode="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/con_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/con_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, the code for java source file.

```
package legacy_systems.contentprovider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Uri allCont = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
        Cursor c;
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <11){
            c = managedQuery(allCont, null, null, null, null);
        }
        else{
            CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(this,
                    allCont,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

            c = cl.loadInBackground();
        }
        String[] columns = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};
        int views[]=new int[]{R.id.con_name, R.id.con_id};
        SimpleCursorAdapter ada;

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<11){
            ada = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main,c, columns, views);
        }
            else
            {
                ada = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main,c, columns, views, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
            }
        this.setListAdapter(ada);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am unable to sort out the problem in it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, just not yet there.

1. You should avoid using your own defined constants as content URIs for the Contacts Provider.
2. You should use the support library implementation of CursorLoader in android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader, and not use managedQuery at all.
3. You're not using CursorLoader correctly. There's a training class for CursorLoader that shows how to use the support library version, at 
   http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html

What may be happening is that you're running the emulator with a platform version of Honeycomb or less, which then uses managedQuery. That works. Your device may be using a later platform version, and then trying to use CursorLoader, and failing.

You've got the right idea, you just need to use the right tactics!

Answer (score 0):

You set your ListView's ID to `@+android:id/lst`. I think you meant to type `list`. If you hadn't used the `+` there, the resource compiler would have been able to tell you about your mistake.

Comment: Sir, I checked the sane app in jelly bean emulator, it worked fine, but somehow, this app doesnot works on a real device. How is that possible ?